# Import csv data to web2py database and process uploads

Tags: python, web2py

I've made a really simple single-user database application with web2py to be deployed to a desktop machine. The reason I choose web2py is due to its simplicity and its not intrusive web server.

My problem is that I need to migrate an existing database from another application that I've just preprocessed and prepared into a csv file that can be now perfectly imported into web2py's sqlite database.

Now, I have a problem with a 'upload' field in one of the tables, which correspond to a small image, I've formated that field into de the csv, with the name of the corresponding .jpg file that I extrated from the original database. The problem is that I have not managed how to insert these correctly into the upload folder, as the web2py engine automatically changes the filename of the users' uploads to a safe format, and copying my files straight to the folder does not work.

My question is, does anyone know a proper way to include this image collection into the uploads folder?. I don't know if there is a way to disable this protection or if I have to manually change their name to a valid hash. I've also considered the idea of coding an automatic insert process into the database...

Thanks all for you attention!

**EDIT (a working example):**

An example database:

```
db.define_table('product',
                Field('name'),
                Field('color'),
                Field('picture', 'upload'),
                )
```

Then using the default appadmin module from my application I import a csv file with entries of the form:

```
product.name,product.color,product.picture
"p1","red","p1.jpg"
"p2","blue","p2.jpg"
```

Then in my application I have the usual download function:

```
def download():
    return response.download(request, db)
```

Which I call requesting the images uploaded into the database, for example, to be included into a view:

```
<img src="{{=URL('download', args=product.picture)}}" />
```

So my problem is that I have all the images corresponding the database records and I need to import them into my application, by properly including them into the uploads folder.

Comment: Any specific code, input, actual and expected outcome?

Comment: updated with and example of the existing input and expected outcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the files to be named via the standard web2py file upload mechanism (which is a good idea for security reasons) and easily downloaded via the built-in `response.download()` method, then you can do something like the following.

In /yourapp/controllers/default.py:

```
def copy_files():
    import os
    for row in db().select(db.product.id, db.product.picture):
        picture = open(os.path.join(request.folder, 'private', row.picture), 'rb')
        row.update_record(picture=db.product.picture.store(picture, row.picture))
    return 'Files copied'
```

Then place all the files in the /yourapp/private directory and go to the URL /default/copy_files (you only need to do this once). This will copy each file into the /uploads directory and rename it, storing the new name in the `db.product.picture` field.

Note, the above function doesn't have to be a controller action (though if you do it that way, you should remove the function when finished). Instead, it could be a script that you run via the web2py command line (needs to be run in the app environment to have access to the database connection and model, as well as reference to the proper /uploads folder) -- in that case, you would need to call `db.commit()` at the end (this is not necessary during HTTP requests).

Alternatively, you can leave things as they are and instead (a) manage uploads and downloads manually instead of relying on web2py's built-in mechanisms, or (b) create `custom_store` and `custom_retrieve` functions (unfortunately, I don't think these are well documented) for the `picture` field, which will bypass web2py's built-in store and retrieve functions. Life will probably be easier, though, if you just go through the one-time process described above.

Comment: Thank you it put me in the right path. I had some problems at the beginning as this approach was giving me the following error:

AttributeError: 'Row' object has no attribute 'update_record'

However I changed the query to:
`for row in db(db.product.id>0).select():`
and then it worked nice. Also I added a `db.commit()` at the end of the script as the changes were not showing correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the `id` field in the select (I have updated the answer with that fix) -- you do not have to select all the fields. Regarding `db.commit()`, that is not necessary in my example, but you are correct that it is necessary when running the code as a script.